# Can someone explain why the "nth-child"-selector has a higher priority than "hover"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Yesterday I ran into this: One of my `:hover`-states stopped working. I found out that If I change this:

```
div.item {}
div.item:hover {}
div.item:nth-child(even) {}
```

to this:

```
div.item {}
div.item:nth-child(even) {}
div.item:hover {}
```

it works again.

I've created a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLLLh/) to show both cases.

Can somebody explain, why the `:hover`-state is overwritten by the selector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The selectors have the same [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), so the one that comes last takes priority.

Comment: +1 Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I thought that there is still some sort of hierarchy within the pseudo-classes.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Nope, the only pseudo-class that is exempt from the usual calculation is `:not()`, which takes on the specificity of its argument instead. This means the specificity of `:not(E)` is `E`, rather than `:not()`.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, so there's at least one exception. Thanks for this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

To override the equal specificity you can chain the selectors

```
div.container_2 > div:nth-child(even):hover {
    background: red;
}​
```

Comment: `div.item:nth-child(even):hover` is enough to increase the specificity - no need to select by parent.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks, you're correct. My placement at the end of the style in the fiddle made it appear that it was more specific.