# Priority of Selector in CSS Rules

Tags: html, css

Let me show the sample code first

```css
#tbl tr:hover {
  background-color: #FFA270 !important;
}

#tbl td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F0FFE2;
}

.cell {
  height: 5ex;
  width: 5em;
  background-color: #E2F1FF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">001</td>
    <td class="cell">002</td>
    <td class="cell">003</td>
    <td class="cell">004</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">001</td>
    <td class="cell">002</td>
    <td class="cell">003</td>
    <td class="cell">004</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">001</td>
    <td class="cell">002</td>
    <td class="cell">003</td>
    <td class="cell">004</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">001</td>
    <td class="cell">002</td>
    <td class="cell">003</td>
    <td class="cell">004</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**What I expect**: The table column is colored by two colors, when mouse hover a cell, the whole row was highlighted with orange.

**What the code actually did**: The table column is colored by two colors, nothing happened when hovering.

I guess the `.cell` and `#tbl td` is more specific than `#tbl tr`, that's why the hover style was ignored, but I don't know how to fix it, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Working with `tr` isn't good. Instead use `td`. Also your selectors must point to same `element` to compare their priority.

Comment: @NOX thanks for the advice, now I know where I was wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain why the "nth-child"-selector has a higher priority than "hover"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055578/can-someone-explain-why-the-nth-child-selector-has-a-higher-priority-than-hov)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a deeper look at specificity:
http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/

`#id` selector = 100 "points"

`.class` and `:pseudo-class` selectors = 10 "points"

In your specific case, this will do the trick:

```
#tbl td:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#F0FFE2;
}
#tbl tr:hover td.cell {
    background-color:#FFA270;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link! I think `#tbl tr:hover .cell` and `#tbl tr:hover td` works the same, but `#tbl tr:hover .cell` should be faster

Comment: By the way, `#tbl tr:hover .cell` has a total specificity of 111 (1 id + 1 pseudo-class + 1 element selectors) while `#tbl tr:hover .cell` "is worth" 121 (1 id + 1 class + 1 pseudo-class + 1 element selectors)

Comment: Avoid mixing up the terms pseudo-class and pseudo-element, especially when discussing specificity, as each has different specificity values!

Comment: Thanks for the link, that "CSS SpeciFISHity" cartoon is really going to help this stick in my mind!