# Why an element having ID and Class needs combination of ID and Class selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to write general CSS rule set (.bg-parallax) and want to apply it to multiple ID based elements.

But why it requires to add the ID selector before Class in CSS selectors? please have a look at below example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="home-cover" class="bg-parallax"> 
     ....
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#home-cover {
}
.bg-parallax {
  Does Not Work?
}
#home-cover.bg-parallax {
   Works - Why do i need ID selector before Class?
}
```

Comment: the second selector is more selective, you can use both

Comment: Because id `#` has high priority than a class `.`

Comment: @DanieleFois, I can not use both, the first one does not work?

Comment: You may have a look at [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
@IrfanDayan it is working http://jsbin.com/xusexonizu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: if it doesn't work you have some other rule interfering with that...

Comment: read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646620/priority-of-selector-in-css-rules

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Can you provide some code where it doesn't work?

Comment: I got it, it was my background property overwriting, it works with both. Thanks to all

Comment: `id` specificity in CSS is a royal pain. As a general rule of thumb avoid using `id` selectors as much as possible in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The hirarachy between IDs and Classes is some of the most important issues to learn when learning CSS & CSS3.

in short, let's explain it through an example. let's say you are gonna buy a car. the car can have a model (like - mazda 3) which is similar to a CSS class. but when you go to the car parking lot, 100 mazda car sit there. but each has a unique serial number - that's the ID in css.

a long article about it is in CSS-Tricks.com: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Enjoy your reading!

Comment: How does this answer the question? Also, it's "hierarchy". Actually, it's not "hierarchy", it's "specificity".

Answer (score 1):

Learn about CSS specificity. [Start here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Here are the basic rules:

1. Id (`#id`) has a specificity of `100`
2. Classes (`.class`) has a specificity of `10`
3. HTML elements (`div`) has a specificity of `1`

> A higher specific selector will override the css properties of a lower
>   specific selector.

Let's look into an example:

```
/* specificity = 100 */
#home-cover {
  font-size: 60px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* specificity = 10 */
.bg-parallax {
  /* will work, since #home-cover doesn't have this property */
  color: red;
  /*will work, same reason as above */
  font-style: italic;
  /* will NOT work, since a higher specific selector (#home-cover) overrides this property */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* will NOT work, same reason as above*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* specificity = 100 + 10 = 110 */
#home-cover.bg-parallax {
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* will work since this selector has higher specificity than #home-cover */
}
```

Here's the working snippet:

```css
/* specificity = 100 */
#home-cover {
  font-size: 60px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* specificity = 10 */
.bg-parallax {
  /* will work, since #home-cover doesn't have this property */
  color: red;
  /*will work, same reason as above */
  font-style: italic;
  /* will NOT work, since a higher specific selector (#home-cover) overrides this property */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* will NOT work, same reason as above*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}


/* specificity = 100 + 10 = 110 */
#home-cover.bg-parallax {
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* will work since this selector has higher specificity than #home-cover */
}
```

```html
<div id="home-cover" class="bg-parallax">CSS Specificty</div>
```